# Extract text from chat windows

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I tried to parse [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX4iX.png) attached followed,
[image]

with the desired outcome of

```
A: "好的呀:)"
B: "Mengjia, 今天的ARN meeting你会从哪里出发呢?"
A: "我今天早的话会从家里出去"
B: "好呀 到时候一起"
B: "顺便跟你取经 怎么转正"
```

I use the following code

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"


# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('D:\C_Drive\Dropbox\Important\Python_Code\self_util\ocr\input\chinese_text.png')

for i in range(3,14):
    print(i)
    # Set the language for OCR to Chinese (Simplified)
    config = (f"-l chi_sim --psm {i}")

    # Perform OCR using Tesseract
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=config)

    # Print the extracted text
    print(text)
```

I got an inaccurate outcome

```
一     我今天早的话会从家里过去。
```

How should I modify it to get the desire outcome? The method is flexible, any method will result in correct output will do.

Answer (score 1):

I had a script similar to your problem and I had no trouble adapting it to propose the following solution. Instead of using pytesseract (very old and difficult to manage) it is better to use paddleocr, a much more powerful ocr model.

This model returns both the ocr and the object detection of the texts, which allows us to play with the coordinates to classify the text results.

I have added comments in the code that I hope are enough for you to understand how it works, if not, do not hesitate to ask.

I leave here the code:

```py
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
import regex as re
from PIL import Image

class ChatOcr:
    def __init__(self, lang = "ch"):
        # Initialize the OCR model using PaddleOCR
        self.model = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang=lang)
    
    def ocr(self, img_path):
        # Read the image and get the size
        img = Image.open(img_path)
        width, height = img.size

        # Run the OCR model
        result = self.model.ocr(img_path, cls=True)[0]

        # Filter the OCR outputs removing the date
        filtered_result = self._filter_ocr_ouputs(result)

        # Classify the OCR outputs in A and B (also merge the lines if they are too close)
        classified_result = self._classify(filtered_result, width, height)

        return classified_result

    def _is_date(self, text):
        text = text.replace(" ", "")

        # Regex pattern for date (based on the format of the date in the chat you posted)
        pattern = r"^([0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{2})?.{,2}[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}[AP]M$"
        match = re.search(pattern, text)
        
        if match:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def _classify(self, filtered_result, width, height):

        # Classify the lines based on the position of the center of the bounding box.
        # If the center is on the left side of the image, the line is classified as A, otherwise as B.

        classified_result = []

        for line in filtered_result:
            center_x = (line["bbox"][0][0] + line["bbox"][1][0]) / 2
            mean_y = (line["bbox"][0][1] + line["bbox"][1][1]) / 2

            if center_x / width < 0.5:
                line["sent_by"] = "A"
            else:
                line["sent_by"] = "B"

            line["mean_y"] = mean_y
            classified_result.append(line)
        
        # Merge the lines if they are too close (the distance between the centers is less than 5% of the height of the image).
        # This is done to merge the lines that are split by the OCR model (multiple lines message).
        mixed_classified_result = []
        discarded_index = []

        for i in range(len(classified_result) - 1):
            if i in discarded_index:
                continue

            if abs(classified_result[i]["mean_y"] - classified_result[i + 1]["mean_y"])/height < 0.05:
                mixed_classified_result.append({
                    "text": classified_result[i]["text"] + classified_result[i + 1]["text"],
                    "sent_by": classified_result[i]["sent_by"],
                })
                discarded_index.append(i + 1)
            
            else:
                mixed_classified_result.append({
                    "text": classified_result[i]["text"],
                    "sent_by": classified_result[i]["sent_by"],
                })
                
        
        if len(classified_result) - 1 not in discarded_index:
            mixed_classified_result.append({
                "text": classified_result[-1]["text"],
                "sent_by": classified_result[-1]["sent_by"],
            })
                
        
        return mixed_classified_result


    def _filter_ocr_ouputs(self, ocr_outputs):

        # Filter the OCR outputs removing the dates and the empty lines
        # The OCR model returns a list of lines, each line is a list of bounding boxes, each bounding box is a list of 4 points, 
        # and the last element is the text with the confidence score.
        result = []

        for line in ocr_outputs:
            text = line[-1][0]
            conf = line[-1][1]

            if self._is_date(text):
                continue

            result.append({
                "text": text,
                "conf": conf,
                "bbox": line[0]
            })

        return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json

    ocr = ChatOcr()

    #Your image renamed to example_1.png
    result = ocr.ocr("example_1.png") 


    for line in result:
        print(line["sent_by"], line["text"])
```

Which outputs:

```bash
B 好的呀
B Mengjia，今天的ARN meeting你会从哪里出发呢?
A 我今天早的话会从家里过去。
B 好呀到时候一起
B 顺便跟你取经怎么转正
```

Also, here you have the `requirements.txt` file:

```bash
paddleocr==2.6.1.3
paddlepaddle==2.4.2
regex==2023.5.5
```

NOTE: emojis are not detected by the model, sorry :(